# About This Mac showing Mojave version 10.14.5 despite updating to 10.14.6

Tags: macos, mojave

I updated my Mac to 10.14.6 yesterday but About This Mac is showing the version as 10.14.5. What is going on?

Comment: Go to System preferences -> Software update and check if the update is indeed installed. Try restarting your Mac.

Comment: Most likely it has not completed.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I did. It wasn't installed. Amazingly it's trying to download the whole thing again!

Comment: @SolarMike It isn't. I did install it yesterday though. It restarted etc.. Now the update file is gone and it's trying to download it again!

Comment: @Alex sometimes it stops due to a program still running in the background...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the update isn't installed. Go to System Preferences app → Software Update and check if an update is shown available.

Either the update is not downloaded or is pending installation. For latter, restarting your Mac should take care of installing it.